# Which is better approach to use to make joblauncher asynchronous?

Tags: spring-batch, job-scheduling

Till date, we were using `spring` inbuilt joblauncher. Now, we have a requirement to run the batch jobs in parallel. We have a total of 9 batch jobs.

I came across 2 scenarios-

`SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`

`ThreadpoolTaskExecutor`

Both these approaches can be used.
Can anyone tell me the pros and cons of each approach  while implementing it in spring batch application?

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` does not reuse threads (See its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html)), so I would recommend using the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` instead for a better usage of resources.